# how to receive and process a photo mms using twilio

Tags: node.js, twilio

Looking for an example, of how to receive and process images via mms to my app using Twilio.

Looking at the number configuration screen in the twilio dashboard, I assume that I set up an incoming phone number and a HTTP POST url to send incoming mms to.  However, I'm not sure what gets posted to that url and don't know the structure of that data.

Does someone have an example of what data gets POSTed to the url and in what format?  Any javascript examples of what data the server would process would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly use the twilio-node module(`npm install twilio`). Once you have that in place, you can just access the webhook request body like you would any request body `req.body`.

As depicted in [twilio's docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request), the structure is like so:

```
{
   MessageSid: String, //ID pertaining to this message
   AccountSid: String, //ID pertaining to your twilio account
   From: String, //phone number of sender
   To: String, //recipients phone number, you in this case
   Body: String, //Message body
   NumMedia: Number, //number of attached media
   //these values only appear when media is present(NumMedia.length > 0)
   MediaContentType: [String] //type of content in SMS
   MediaUrl: [String] //URL to download the media
}
```

You can then do something like this using the twilio modules, caolan/async module, and the popular [request/request](https://github.com/request/request) module:

```
var twilio  = require('twilio'),
    fs      = require('fs'),
    async   = require('async'),
    request = require('request');

app.post('/mms', function(req, res) {
    var options = { url: 'https://subtle-gradient-188.herokuapp.com/twiml' };
    if (!twilio.validateExpressrequire(req, 'YOUR_TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN', options)) return res.status(401).send("Bad key!");

    if(!req.body.hasOwnProperty('MediaUrl')) return res.send("Missing media...");

    var media = req.body.MediaUrl;

    //download all media
    async.map(media, download, function(err, filenames) {

        var resp = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
        if(err) {
            resp.say("Problem occured");
            console.log(err);
        }
        else resp.say('Files recieved: ' + filenames.join(', '));
        res.type('text/xml');
        res.send(resp.toString());
    });
});

//download a single url to a unique filename
function download(url, cb) {
    var name = Date.now() + url.split('/').pop();

    request
        .get(url)
        .on('error', cb)
        .on('end', function() {
            cb(null, name);
        })
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(name));
}
```

Comment: I noticed that twilio returns the media object not as an array but rather as a named property, e.g. MediaContentType0 MediaUrl0

Comment: Some people do that, but you can usually access the property the same way as an array as long as the key is a Number not a string.